# How to override joomla 3 component template in 2 places?

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla3.2

How can i override template for com_content in two different pages?
For example I have a menu with two pages "Page1" and "Page2".
And I need for com_content in a Page1 must be with one html template,
and com_content in a Page2 must be with another html template.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the template override and put it under:

```
/templates/*your_template/html/com_content/article/*template_name.php
```

Then you could select the layout at:

```
Article -> Options -> Alternative Layout
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello. May be are you know how to override a category blog layout as well?

Comment: As far as I know there is a bug in category blog override, please try to make a google search.

Comment: Are you mean bug in latest version 3.3.5/3.3.6?

Comment: I think it's in all J3 versions.